# How to get dictionary value by key

Tags: typescript

This is my dict:

```
export const roles = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
};
```

I want to get the value by key like so:

```
let x = "key1"; 
let y = roles[x]
```

And I'm getting the error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ key1: string; key2: string;
> key3: string; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type
> 'string' was found on type '{ key1: string; key2: string; key3:
> string; }'.ts(7053)

How do I do it right?

Comment: `let x: keyof roles = "key1";`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure this our with an interface like so:

```
interface LoosObject {
[key: string]: any
}

export const roles: LoosObject = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
};
```